# How to share shiny apps with coworkers for free?

Tags: r, shiny, share, shiny-server

Is there a way to share shiny apps internally with non-R users for free with unlimited hours? Also, due to the sensitivity of the data, I'd prefer not to have it open to the public.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-shiny-server-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Have you looked at shiny server? It's a free open source utility: https://www.rstudio.com/products/shiny/shiny-server/. But produce recommendations aren't really on topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I set up my own servers on digital ocean. It was not too bad of a learning curve if you have installed other things on ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The best solution is:
https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio-server-pro/
but if you want a free version you can get:
https://www.rstudio.com/products/shiny/shiny-server/

and for example add:
https://www.shinyproxy.io/
for authentication (if you need).

or 
docker and https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/shiny/

Comment: Unfortunately, I use MacOS and not Linux OS. Is there any alternative for MacOS?

Comment: I updated the post. Docker is the best solution for you!

Comment: What about Windows?

Comment: @VisheshShrivastav Docker is also the best solution!