# How to share Rshiny dashboard with coworkers for free?

Tags: r, shinydashboard

I have prepared a shiny dashboard using Rmarkdown in R. How do I share the dashboard with coworkers so that they can view and interact with the dashboard for free without any R IDE ?

Please suggest the steps to follow to share the dashboard privately to cowokers.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: It's a duplicate from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53157548/how-to-share-shiny-apps-with-coworkers-for-free

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to share shiny apps with coworkers for free?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53157548/how-to-share-shiny-apps-with-coworkers-for-free)

Comment: I actually saw this link but how can I share this privately without putting it on web

Comment: Also I am using windows, I can't find installation guide for Rstudio connect to publish my dashboard